# How to fun out in RxGo

Tags: go, reactive

I'm trying to fun out the final step of my reactive flow to achieve parallel execution of the final step using DoOnNext.

Running the code bellow I expect that thirdCounter = 2 and every "first DoOnNext", "second DoOnNext" and
"third DoOnNext" will be printer twice (total 6 times)

The printing are as expected and also the Map concat the strings correctly. However, the **thirdCounter = 7** hence the steps are over invoked.

What I'm missing here?

My code:

```
var thirdCounter int32
func localRun(names ...string) {
    observable := rxgo.Just(names)().
        Map(func(_ context.Context, i interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
            s := i.(string)
            s = fmt.Sprintf("%s,%s", s, "one")
            return s, nil
        }).
        Map(func(_ context.Context, i interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
            s := i.(string)
            s = fmt.Sprintf("%s,%s", s, "two")
            return s, nil
        }).
        Map(func(_ context.Context, i interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
            atomic.AddInt32(&thirdCounter, 1)
            s := i.(string)
            s = fmt.Sprintf("%s,%s", s, "three")
            return s, nil
        })

    observable.DoOnNext(func(i interface{}) {
        fmt.Println("first DoOnNext", i)
    })

    observable.DoOnNext(func(i interface{}) {
        fmt.Println("second DoOnNext", i)
    })

    observable.DoOnNext(func(i interface{}) {
        fmt.Println("third DoOnNext", i)
    })

    for item := range observable.Last().Observe() {
        fmt.Println(item.V)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Third Counter = %d\n", thirdCounter)
}
func TestMocktFlow(t *testing.T) {
    cs := make([]string, 0)
    cs = append(cs, "Hello")
    cs = append(cs, "Hi")
    localRun(cs...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 3 subscribers. Your code has 4 subscribers.

1. first DoOnNext()
2. second DoOnNext()
3. third DoOnNext()
4. observable.Last()

So you should expect thirdCounter=8.
If you wait until all subscriptions end,
You can see that 8 is output.

Change the last part of the code to the following:

```golang
time.Sleep(time.Second) // added
fmt.Printf("Third Counter = %d\n", thirdCounter) // 8
```